# Quantitative Physiology Textbooks Recommendations?

Tags: human-biology, physiology, human-physiology, theoretical-biology

I am currently completing a 2nd year (UK) Mamamilian Physiology Module and a Neuroscience Module. However, my degree is also 40% Maths and Statistics. So in order to learn the content better, I am thinking I may be more suited to a quantitative first explanation before the qualitative description.

I am asking here as I don't want the biology to be glossed over as I am being assessed by Physiology Professors not my Statistics Professor

Comment: Has your professor suggested any book as a part of the course?

Comment: @RoniSaiba yes the Pocock and Richards Textbooks and points us to research papers in the slides